# Systemd to upstart

Tags: linux, ubuntu, systemd, upstart

I got a systemd service and I am still using Ubuntu 14.04 for various reasons. As you probably know ubuntu uses upstart and not systemd. Can you guys help me convert this systemd service to an upstart service ?

```
[Unit]
Description=Conan - dong sliders to MAX
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/steam/exiles/start_conan.sh
User=steam
Type=simple
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=42s

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: You can read the [Getting Started](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/getting-started.html) provided by the upstart developer. This will help you for sure.

Comment: Also, as an aside, what with the early access and no dedicated linux server available yet this probably isn't the best time to try and set up an Exiles server. I've tried, and it kind of works, but things are sort of messy still.

Comment: I thought 14.04 had sysVinit, too. So just copy `/etc/init.d/skeleton` to `/etc/init.d/myjob and edit the start) and restart). Put `/home/steam/exiles/start_conan.sh` in start) and `stop;sleep 42;start` in restart). Then run `update-rc.d defaults myjob` if I remember correctly.

Comment: @Shadur It's more or less testing. Nothing serious planned yet, but we have some ressources left on our server. Michael Thanks, will try that out

Comment: I strongly urge you to consider upgrading. 14.04 is no longer supported, so you will be facing many issues going forward.

Comment: We will upgrade anyway once we change our hoster in the near future. I am not quite getting what to do @MichaelD. I might be blind but I cannot seem to find where to put the path ? I uploaded the skeleton, maybe someone can help me out and make the changes ?https://ufile.io/ea753

Comment: @SaeSi can you post the content of your script `/home/steam/exiles/start_conan.sh` ? I'd include that into the new skel. file

Comment: @MichaelD. Thanks for you help https://ufile.io/2d09a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As root:

- Save the following text as `/etc/init.d/conan`.
- Set executable flag `chmod +x /etc/init.d/conan`.
- Try to run it: `/etc/init.d/conan start`
- all good? add it to the runlevels `update-rc.d conan defaults`

> ```
> #! /bin/sh
> PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
> DESC="conan service"
> NAME=conan
> DAEMON=/usr/sbin/$NAME
> DAEMON_ARGS="--options args"
> PIDFILE=/var/run/$NAME.pid
> SCRIPTNAME=/etc/init.d/$NAME
> . /lib/init/vars.sh
> . /lib/lsb/init-functions
> case "$1" in
> start)
>     log_daemon_msg "Starting $DESC" "$NAME"
>     export DISPLAY=:0
>     export WINEARCH=win64
>     export WINEPREFIX=/home/steam/.wine64
>     xvfb-run --auto-servernu m--server-args='-screen 0 640x480x24:32' wine /home/steam/exiles/common/Conan/ConanSandboxServer.exe -log -QueryPort=27055 &
>     ;;
> stop)
>     log_daemon_msg "Stopping $DESC" "$NAME"
>     wineserver -k
>     #wineserver -k9
>     ;;
> status)
>         [ $(pgrep -f wine | wc -l) -gt 0 ] && log_daemon_msg "is running" || log_daemon_msg "not running"
>     ;;
> restart)
>     stop
>     sleep 2
>     start
>     ;;
> *)
>     echo "Usage: $SCRIPTNAME {start|stop|status|restart}" >&2
>     exit 3
>     ;;
> esac
> ```

Comment: Thanks for your help. One last question, how do I start this script in a new screen ? Sorry for all the "stupid" questions but the whole init thing is totally new for me. I was glad a few days ago to write a simple shell script but I cannot quite connect the dots yet :/

Comment: Screen as in Terminal? https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html

Comment: This might work, but it's not an Upstart script, it's a SysVinit script.

Comment: @MarkStosberg yes, check 3rd comment below question.